# Where are the POSIX message functions (msgsnd, msgrcv, etc) man pages in Mac?

Tags: macos, message, manpage

I wanted to view the manual pages for the POSIX standard message functions: msgsnd, msgrcv, etc. All of them are defined in sys/msg.h and code using them works. But the manual pages are nowhere to be found, neither in my computer (Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3), in my friends' (OS X Lion) or in the developer pages of Apple in Internet.

Where can I download that manual so I can access it right from terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has not published man pages for that family of functions. I would suggest filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ requesting that they be published. In the mean time you could use the [FreeBSD man pages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=msgsnd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for reference as that's likely to be where the OS X implementation originated.